# How can I find out why the for loop doesn't work at all?

Tags: python-3.x, function, file, for-loop, turtle-graphics

I'm not sure why my program doesn't enter the for loop at all, the code is below:

```
    ### Retrieve and edit polygons
    def buttonEdit():
        for line in myFile:
            ptList = line.strip('[]').split(',')
            for pt in range(1, len(ptList)):
                t.pendown()
                t.goto(ptList[pt][0], ptList[pt][1])

    ### Store polygons in a file
    while True:
        try:
            myFile = open("polygon_data.txt", 'a+')
            break
        except OSError:
            print("File does not exist, please try again!")
```

Comment: The posted code never calls the `buttonEdit` function, so of course no `for` loop is ever run

Comment: Where is the function getting `myFile` from?  Are you sure there is data in it and the file pointer is at the beginning of the file?  (Perhaps the `for` loop over a file automatically starts at the beginning, but I'm not sure)